# Show that $x^2\equiv1\pmod{2^b}$ has four solutions when $b\geq3$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to prove this equation with number theory and not abstract algebra. If $x^2\equiv1\pmod{2^b}$ (read $1$ mod $2^b$), then $2^b\mid(x^2-1)$, leaving us with $2^b\mid(x-1)$ or  $2^b\mid(x+1)$. $x$ has to be odd since $2^b$ is even, so $(x-1)(x+1)=(2k-1+1)(2k+1+1)=4k(k+1)$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. It is clear $4(k)(k+1)\equiv0(2^b)$. Since $2^b=2^{b-2}\cdot2^2$, the equivalence becomes $4(k)(k+1)\equiv0(2^{b-2})\cdot4$. If we multiply both sides by the inverse of $4$, then we get $k(k+1)\equiv0(2^{b-2})$.

Here is where I run into issues. I understand that cases arise because $k$ can be odd or even, taking the form $k=2l$ or $k=2l+1$ depending on the case. I back myself into $2l(2l+1)\equiv0(2^{b-2})$ or $(2l+1)(2l+1+1)\equiv0(2^{b-2})$, respectively. I know from the case of $b=2$ that we have two solutions, which (in this case) would be $x^2\equiv\pm1(4)$. I've seen solutions elsewhere described as $\pm1$ as well as $2^{b-1}\pm1$, but frankly I don't understand the intermediate steps and no one has explained them in the sources.

Can someone please fill in the details for me?

Comment: "leaving us with $2^b\mid(x-1)$ or $2^b\mid(x+1)$" is not correct, as you can see by letting $b=4$ and $x=7$, for which $16\mid(49-1)$ but $16\not\mid(7-1)$ and $16\not\mid(7+1)$. (What is correct is that $2^{b-1}$ divides one of the two factors, while the other is divisible only by $2$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: The 4 solutions are $1,-1,1+2^{b-1}, 2^{b-1}-1$. Note that $2^b$ can divide $x^2-1$ without dividing either one of $(x-1)$, $(x+1)$, as one could be even i.e., divisible by $2$ and the other divisible by $2^{b-1}$. This is precisely what happens for $x=2^{b-1}\pm 1$.

Comment: And to see that those 4 solutions are the only solutions, note that $4$ cannot divide both $(x-1)$ and $(x+1)$. So one of these is divisible by $2$ and not $4$ and so not any higher power of $2$, requiring the other to be divisible by $2^{b-1}$.

Comment: How can I notate that? $2^{b-1}$ is still even, so wouldn't that make the other choice odd?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "as one could be even and the other divisible by". Are you talking about $x-1$ and $x+1$?

Comment: Yes. Take $b=3$ and play around with $x=1,7$ and then $x=3,5$.

Comment: If you still are not satisfied, $b=4$ and $x=1,15$ and then $x=7,9$. And then $b=5$ and $x=1,31$ and $x=15,17$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think we're I'm getting hung up the most is the how to phrase the step  that one of the terms is divisible by $2$ and one of the terms is divisible by $2^{b-1}$. I see what you're saying about the case when we're in mod $8$. For example, $x^2=7$ implies that $8$ divides 49-1, or more specifically $2\mid6$ and $8\mid4$. 

I think what I want to say is that in general once we get it to the $(2k)(2k+2)$ step, that $2\mid(2k+2)$ and $2k\mid2^{b-1}$. I feel there's a better way to say that. How should I rephrase it?

Comment: Put my answer--just editted slightly, and my 1st comment together.

Comment: I appreciate it; thank you.